# How I integrate NLP with solr for NLP search

Tags: solr, nlp

I am working on solr 8 version. I want to integrate solr with NLP improve the search relevancy. I am unable to find any solution. please help me to configure and intergrate solr with NLP

Comment: You've got no details about what you're trying to achieve and how you're planning on achieve it - you've got to narrow down the question to get any useful answers. Start by looking at the OpenNLP integration in Solr: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/language-analysis.html#opennlp-integration

Answer (score 0):

Here is a starting point for what you are asking for, for the 8.2 solr version:

[Integrating openNLP with solr 8.2](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/language-analysis.html#opennlp-integration)

Also, here is another link where you can see some things in action with openNLP and solr with respect to search relevancy:

[Named Entity Extraction with OpenNLP](https://sematext.com/blog/entity-extraction-opennlp-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Medium post on how to add embedding to solr. I suggested you to use Sentence-transformers from Huggingface library to build sentence embedding.

https://medium.com/swlh/fun-with-apache-lucene-and-bert-embeddings-c2c496baa559